# Gnuplot Hide Command Line Prompt Terminal

Tags: ruby, windows, terminal, gnuplot, command-prompt

I'm running Gnuplot in one of my applications and every time I generate a graph and run the executable, the Windows command line prompt displays for a short period of time before closing itself. Is there a way to hide the terminal and keep it from displaying?

Here's a section of the code I'm using:

```
# Create gnuplot
Gnuplot.open do |gp|
    Gnuplot::Plot.new( gp ) do |plot|
        plot.set("terminal", "png small size 800,500")
        plot.set("title", File.basename(@current_epw_file))
        plot.set("ylabel", "\"y1\" rotate by 0")
        plot.set("y2label", "\"y2\" rotate by 0")
        plot.set("bmargin", "7")
        if (@show_grid)
            plot.set("grid")
        end

        plot.set("xdata","time")
        plot.set("timefmt", "\"%m/%d %H:%M\"")
        plot.set("format", "x \"%m/%d\\n%H:%M\"")
        plot.set("xrange", xrange)
        plot.set("y2tics")
        plot.set("key", "under")

        # Insert day markers if that option is selected
        if (@mark_days)
            day_markers = generate_day_markers(xrange)
            day_markers.each do |marker|
                plot.set("arrow", "from \"#{marker} 0:00\",graph(0,0) to \"#{marker} 0:00\",graph(1,1) nohead")
            end
        end

        plot.set("output", "weather_display.png")
        plot.data = []

        # Load all the data sets
        for file in dataset_files
            plot.data << Gnuplot::DataSet.new( "'#{file}'" ) do |ds|
                weather_parameter_object = @requested_parameters.slice!(0)

                ds.with = @with_value

                # Check thick lines option
                if (!@thick_lines)
                    ds.linewidth = 1
                else
                    ds.linewidth = 2
                end

                ds.using = "1:3"
                y_axis = @parameter_axes.slice!(0)
                ds.axes = "x1y#{y_axis}"
                if (using_both_axes)
                    ds.title = "#{weather_parameter_object.name} (#{weather_parameter_object.units}) [y#{y_axis}]"
                else
                    ds.title = "#{weather_parameter_object.name} (#{weather_parameter_object.units})"
                end
            end 
        end
    end

    path = Plugin.dir + "/lib/ruby/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/gnuplot-2.6.2/gnuplot/bin/weather_display.png"
    while (File.exists?(path) and File.size(path) > 0)
        # Wait until image has been created
    end

end
```

Comment: rubyw.exe perhaps, instead of ruby.exe?

Comment: See also http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Running_Multiple_Processes#Windows:_how_to_run_ruby_without_opening_up_a_command_window

Comment: The problem is that I'm developing a plugin for Trimble SketchUp, so I don't actually call the ruby executable.

Comment: yeah after some further investigation, appears you'll have to use some ffi CreateProcess love (see the link above) which...gnuplot doesn't support hmm...